# SQL Query - Subqueries On Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

### Intro

I have a complex query I need to write (for an Oracle DB). I've tried to make an analogy to avoid using company data, so let me know if something seems weird.

### Tables

CAT

- CAT_ID (PK)

KITTEN

- KITTEN_ID (PK)

CAT_KITTEN_PLAY

- PLAY_ID (PK)
- CAT_ID (FK to CAT table)
- KITTEN_ID (FK to KITTEN table)
- KITTEN_GENDER (String - M or F)
- PLAY_TIME (Date)

KITTEN_INFO

- KITTEN_ID (FK to KITTEN table)
- NAME (String, e.g. "Name")
- VALUE (String, e.g. "Duchess")

### Description

So basically, the CAT and KITTEN tables just hold IDs and some other random information. KITTEN_INFO holds the name of the kittens (among other things). And CAT_KITTEN_PLAY logs all of the times a cat plays with a kitten.

What I need, is to write a query that returns all of the CATs whose most recent play time with a male KITTEN was in a certain date range. Let's call it Jan 1 2011 to Jan 31 2011. I also need to include the play date and name of the most recent male and female kitten the cat played with.

### So Far

Below is what I have so far:

```
SELECT cat.*, lastMale.PLAY_TIME maleTime, lastFemale.PLAY_TIME femaleTime, maleName.VALUE male, femaleName.VALUE female
FROM CAT cat
LEFT JOIN CAT_KITTEN_PLAY lastMale ON lastMale.CAT_ID = cat.CAT_ID 
                                  AND lastMale.GENDER = 'M'
LEFT JOIN CAT_KITTEN_PLAY lastFemale ON lastFemale.CAT_ID = cat.CAT_ID 
                                    AND lastFemale.GENDER = 'F'
LEFT JOIN KITTEN_INFO femaleName ON femaleName.KITTEN_ID = lastFemale.KITTEN_ID 
                                AND maleName.NAME = 'Name'
LEFT JOIN KITTEN_INFO maleName ON maleName.KITTEN_ID = lastMale.KITTEN_ID 
                              AND femaleName.NAME = 'Name'
    WHERE lastMale.PLAY_TIME BETWEEN '01-JAN-2011 12:00:00 AM'
                                 AND '31-JAN-2011 11:59:59 PM'
```

### Problems

This does not account for the fact that a cat may have played with a make/female kitten more than once. So, I'd want to add "AND lastMale.PLAY_TIME = (SELECT MAX(PLAY_TIME) FROM CAT_KITTEN_PLAY WHERE CAT_ID = cat.ID AND KITTEN_GENDER = 'M')" onto the first join, and a similar one to the second join. But subqueries are not allowed on joins.

Any thoughts? Note that a cat may have never played with a female kitten. But the cat should still be included if they meet the criteria (hence the left joins).

Comment: Note: adding "AND lastFemale.PLAY_TIME = (SELECT MAX(PLAY_TIME) WHERE ..." etc to the end won't work, as that will delete all the cats who haven't played with a female kitten.

Comment: Why is `KITTEN_GENDER` stored in `CAT_KITTEN_PLAY`? Isn't it essentially part of `KITTEN_INFO`?

Comment: Remember, analogy. Makes more sense in my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analytic functions are probably the best answer to your problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       cat.*, 
       first_value(lastMale.PLAY_TIME) 
          over (partition by cat.id 
                order by lastMale.PLAY_TIME desc nulls last) maleTime,
       first_value(lastFemale.PLAY_TIME) 
          over (partition by cat.id 
                order by lastFemale.PLAY_TIME desc nulls last) femaleTime,
       first_value(maleName.VALUE)  
          over (partition by cat.id 
                order by lastMale.PLAY_TIME desc nulls last) male,
       first_value(femaleName.VALUE)  
          over (partition by cat.id 
                order by lastFemale.PLAY_TIME desc nulls last) female
...
```

Comment: If I do this and any of the PLAY_TIME values are blank, all of the values in the column come back blank. Maybe because it's always grabbing the first, regardless of the cat ID?

Comment: Yeah, looks like all of the femaleTime values are whatever the first value is (blank or no).

Comment: See the following. The columns always contain the same value: http://gerardnico.com/wiki/database/oracle/first_value

Comment: The reason you were seeing empty columns is that I specified `desc` without `nulls last` (see edit).  Adding `partition by` gives you the value over the specified condition. Without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it's tough to provide a fully tested solution.

Comment: Awesome, looks like it's working. Thanks so much. Hopefully I can extend this to the whole query. Which contains about a billion joins. Damn DB designers. Lol. Thanks again. You made my life a lot easier. =)

Comment: +1 wow first_value is really nice. Do you happen to know when it was introduced

Comment: [Analytic functions](http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html) (like `first_value`) were introduced in 8i.  There is a caveat, in that they do not always perform well because they have to operate over the entire result set, but for some of the things they do (notably `lag` and `lead`) they're indispensable.

Answer (score 1):

Just times of last play, not names of Kittens:

```
SELECT cat.CAT_ID
     , MAX(play.PLAY_TIME) AS maleTime
     , ( SELECT MAX(playf.PLAY_TIME)
         FROM CAT_KITTEN_PLAY AS playf
         WHERE playf.CAT_ID = cat.CAT_ID
           AND playf.KITTEN_GENDER = 'F'
       ) AS femaleTime
FROM CAT AS cat
  JOIN CAT_KITTEN_PLAY AS play
    ON play.CAT_ID = cat.CAT_ID
WHERE play.KITTEN_GENDER = 'M'
GROUP BY cat.CAT_ID 
HAVING MAX(play.PLAY_TIME) BETWEEN '01-JAN-2011 12:00:00 AM'
                               AND '31-JAN-2011 11:59:59 PM'
```

---

Not at all sure that this will work:

```
SELECT cat.CAT_ID
     , lastplayM.PLAY_TIME AS maleTime
     , lastplayF.PLAY_TIME AS femaleTime
     , kittenM.VALUE AS male
     , kittenF.VALUE AS female
FROM CAT AS cat
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT CAT_ID
           , KITTEN_GENDER
           , KITTEN_ID
           , MAX(PLAY_TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY CAT_ID, KITTEN_GENDER) AS PLAY_TIME
      FROM CAT_KITTEN_PLAY
      WHERE PLAY_TIME = MAX(PLAY_TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY CAT_ID, KITTEN_GENDER)
    ) AS lastplayM
    ON lastplayM.CAT_ID = cat.CAT_ID
    AND lastplayM.KITTEN_GENDER = 'M'
    AND lastplayM.PLAY_TIME BETWEEN '01-JAN-2011 12:00:00 AM'
                               AND '31-JAN-2011 11:59:59 PM'
  JOIN KITTEN_INFO AS kittenM
    ON kittenM.KITTEN_ID = lastplayM.KITTEN_ID

  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT CAT_ID
           , KITTEN_GENDER
           , KITTEN_ID
           , MAX(PLAY_TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY CAT_ID, KITTEN_GENDER) AS PLAY_TIME
      FROM CAT_KITTEN_PLAY
      WHERE PLAY_TIME = MAX(PLAY_TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY CAT_ID, KITTEN_GENDER)
    ) AS lastplayF
    ON lastplayF.CAT_ID = cat.CAT_ID
    AND lastplayF.KITTEN_GENDER = 'F'
  JOIN KITTEN_INFO AS kittenF
    ON kittenF.KITTEN_ID = lastplayF.KITTEN_ID
```

Comment: How would you add the names then? Seems like some of the referencing has gotten lost.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I went with the FIRST_VALUE solution by Allan. Is a bit clearier in my opinion. But thanks for the hard work =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the WITH clause to make this somewhat easier

```
WITH MAX_MALE_KITTEN AS
(

     SELECT
        CAT_ID,
        MAX(PLAY_TIME) PLAY_TIME
     FROM
        CAT_KITTEN_PLAY
     WHERE
        KITTEN_GENDER = 'M'
     GROUP BY
        CAT_ID
),
MAX_FEMALE_KITTEN AS
(

     SELECT
        CAT_ID,
        MAX(PLAY_TIME) PLAY_TIME
     FROM
        CAT_KITTEN_PLAY
     WHRE
        KITTEN_GENDER = 'F'
     GROUP BY
        CAT_ID
)

SELECT
    C.CAT_ID,
    F_K_I.NAME LastFemaleName,
    F_PLAY_INFO.PLAY_TIME LastFemalePlayTime,
    M_K_I.NAME LastMaleName,
    M_PLAY_INFO.PLAY_TIME LastMalePlayTime

FROM
    CAT C
    LEFT JOIN CAT_KITTEN_PLAY F_PLAY_INFO
    ON C.CAT_ID = F_PLAY_INFO.CAT_ID
    AND F_PLAY_INFO.KITTEN_GENER= 'F'
    LEFT JOIN MAX_FEMALE_KITTEN M_F_K
    ON F_PLAY_INFO.CAT_ID = M_F_K.CAT_ID
    AND F_PLAY_INFO.PLAY_TIME = M_F_K.PLAY_TIME
    LEFT JOIN KITTEN_INFO F_K_I
    ON F_PLAY_INFO.KITTEN_ID = F_K_I.KITTEN_ID

    INNER JOIN CAT_KITTEN_PLAY M_PLAY_INFO
    ON C.CAT_ID = M_PLAY_INFO.CAT_ID
    AND M_PLAY_INFO.KITTEN_GENER= 'M'
    LEFT JOIN MAX_MALE_KITTEN M_F_K
    ON M_PLAY_INFO.CAT_ID = M_F_K.CAT_ID
    AND M_PLAY_INFO.PLAY_TIME = M_F_K.PLAY_TIME
    LEFT JOIN KITTEN_INFO M_K_I
    ON M_PLAY_INFO.KITTEN_ID = M_K_I.KITTEN_ID
WHERE 
       MAX_MALE_KITTEN.PLAY_TIME    BETWEEN '01-JAN-2011 12:00:00 AM'
                           AND '31-JAN-2011 11:59:59 PM
```